# how to return value from this scope (Node.js)

Tags: node.js

I have a Node.js module which return memory used:

```
 //meminfo.js
 module.exports = myObj;

 myObj = (function() {
 var pub = {};
 pub.getmem = function() {
     meminfo.list(function(memused) {
         return memused;
     }); 
 };
 return pub;
 })();
```

If I want to retrieve memused by this:

```
 //main.js

 var meminfo = require('./meminfo');
 console.log(myObj.getmem());
```

Then could you give me some suggestions about how to return 'memused' from this in meminfo.js:

```
  meminfo.list(function(memused) {
       return memused;
  });
```

Comment: @torazaburo could you please explain more

Comment: No, you should consult all the resources out there about promises. Basically, you create a promise in meminfo and return it, and "resolve" it within the callback. Then, the consumer does something like `myObj.getmem().then(function(val) { console.log(val); })`.

Comment: Hi @torazaburo, no offense, I think we need to know meminfo.list is execute async or not. If it execute sync then just return directly inside getmem is enough.

Comment: Even if it's not async, there's no way to return a result from inside a callback.

Comment: Do you mean that I cannot use return memused; inside meminfo.list(function (memused) {return memused;}) ?